Use Python to select vertices in Blender 4 so I don't have to select them manually each time?
I'm importing a copy of the same mesh every day. I'm selecting the same vertices on the mesh and creating vertex groups from the selections. It's time consuming to select the vertices by hand. Since I always need to select the same vertices on the same mesh, I was wondering if there was some way to record my selection once, and use scripting to make the selection from now on?
I did look at some posts with similar titles, but they seemed to describe a different problem.
I have a beginner understanding of how Python scripting works in Blender. I just started using it and I've only made one script so far to create, name, position and parent a bone.
I'm using Blender 4.0
Thanks much for any information/help

do you create also the same vertex groups?

Sounds like you could use the data transfer modifier

Could you define 'copy' a bit more closely? From the question as written, it's not immediately clear why you are re-importing.. why you don't just retain the mesh with its assigned vertex-group.

I wonder if this is an XY problem and I just wasted my time  on an answer... Well, good to encourage someone to learn Python in any case, I guess...

Thank you so much. This is exactly what I wanted to do and your answer was easy for me to understand. The reason I need to keep using the same mesh is because I am iterating and adding morphs in a different app then importing to Blender for weight painting. I use the vertex groups to do precise weight editing with parameters rather than the brush tool.

If it's the same mesh, the indices of vertices should not change, so you could select them by index. You could select the vertices you wish and make yourself a list:
import bpy

vertices = bpy.context.object.data.vertices

selected_verts = []

for v in vertices:
    if v.select:
        selected_verts.append(v.index)
    
print(selected_verts)

You get the list printed in the System Console

Then you can select the same vertices by running this with the list copied from the console:
import bpy

vertices = bpy.context.object.data.vertices

verts_to_select = [1, 3, 8, 9, 11, 12, 22, 24, 25, 34, 35, 37, 38, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 74, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100]

for i in verts_to_select:
    vertices[i].select = True

Note that this only works from object mode. So you have to switch to object mode when running the scripts from the text editor. It will not deselect any already selected geometry. If you wanted to deselect what's selected you would need to deselect vertices, edges and faces since those are different things under the hood. See this answer
You can also have a look at Templates menu in the text editor to see how to put this in to an add-on or an operator so you can assign a hotkey.
Off course you could just add the list of vertices to a vertex group as well:
import bpy

vertices = bpy.context.object.data.vertices

verts_to_group = [1, 3, 8, 9, 11, 12, 22, 24, 25, 34, 35, 37, 38, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 74, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100]

bpy.context.object.vertex_groups["Group"].add(verts_to_group, 1, "ADD")

